# how to set font size in "\rput"?

Tags: fonts, pstricks

I can set the font in `\rput` like this

```
\rput(-0.76,0.7){\tiny $1$}
```

But how can I set more exact font in rput? for example: `6pt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is `\rput(2,2){\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont$1$}`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido,mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=5+5}{20}{
\begin{pspicture}(4,4)
    \rput(2,2){\fontsize{\i pt}{\i pt}\selectfont$1$}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @PSTikZ, it works well. I would like to ask, because this should have somewhere in the manual, where can i find it by myself? Thanks again!

Comment: Note that this is not specific to `\rput`: it's a general point about font selection in LaTeX.